# Understand Regular Expression

Tags: regex

What does this regular expression mean \w+(?=@). Im trying to understand how this expression will pull users from the AD, currently it is omitting all characters before a special Character. Ex: Viny.Trucker will result only in .Truck. I want the whole name Viny.Trucker to be extracted.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It means find "any number of word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _) immediately followed by an @ symbol. The @ symbol won't be included in the matched characters. If you want to include the '.' character in the expression, you can try (\w|.)+(?=@)

Comment: `\w` includes also `[0-9_]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : http://www.regexr.com/ It comes with very nice explanation when you hover over chars.
And here is your regex : http://www.regexr.com/38ndp

Answer (score 0):

It matches the characters before an @-character.

```
\w+    Match at least one word-character, i.e. letters, numbers and underscores.
(?=@)  Match an @-character without including it in the match.
```

Answer (score 0):

Jan AAgaard is right, it matches all word characters before an `@`.

## How does it do this?

```
\w+   Matches ones or more word-chracters.
(?=@) This is called a positive-lookahead. It means require the following to come after the characters, but don't include that in the match.
```

## A better alternative

Now, it seems that you want to match every character before an `@`, the easy way to to this is

```
[^@]+(?=@)
```

If you know that there will always be a `@` in a line you could even use

```
[^@]+
```

and just take the first match.
If there will always be a certain set of chracters allowed before the `@`, you could even specify those in a *character class*: Simply put all of them in square brackets, e.g.:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9._]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's searching for `any character, digit or underscore` followed by **@**

```
\w+(?=@)


Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=@)»
   Match the character “@” literally «@»
```

**Positive and Negative Lookahead**

> Negative lookahead is indispensable if you want to match something not
>   followed by something else. When explaining character classes, this
>   tutorial explained why you cannot use a negated character class to
>   match a q not followed by a u. Negative lookahead provides the
>   solution: q(?!u). The negative lookahead construct is the pair of
>   parentheses, with the opening parenthesis followed by a question mark
>   and an exclamation point. Inside the lookahead, we have the trivial
>   regex u.
>
> Positive lookahead works just the same. q(?=u) matches a q that is
>   followed by a u, without making the u part of the match. The positive
>   lookahead construct is a pair of parentheses, with the opening
>   parenthesis followed by a question mark and an equals sign. You can
>   use any regular expression inside the lookahead (but not lookbehind,
>   as explained below). Any valid regular expression can be used inside
>   the lookahead. If it contains capturing groups then those groups will
>   capture as normal and backreferences to them will work normally, even
>   outside the lookahead. (The only exception is Tcl, which treats all
>   groups inside lookahead as non-capturing.) The lookahead itself is not
>   a capturing group. It is not included in the count towards numbering
>   the backreferences. If you want to store the match of the regex inside
>   a lookahead, you have to put capturing parentheses around the regex
>   inside the lookahead, like this: (?=(regex)). The other way around
>   will not work, because the lookahead will already have discarded the
>   regex match by the time the capturing group is to store its match.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html